# Missing type annotation for `T`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, flowtype

I am trying to build code with simple javascript function below:

```
filterArray(user: any, items: Array<Object>) {
    items = items.filter(item => {return true;});
    return items;
}
```

But I am getting below error:

```
Missing type annotation for `T`. `T` is a type parameter declared in array type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at
call of method `filter` [2].

   src/mod/test.js:69:15
   69|       items = items.filter(item => {return true;});
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [2]

References:
   src/mod/test.js:69:15
   69|       items = items.filter(item => {return true;});
                     ^^^^^ [1]
```

I am using flow and building using npm.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this error](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swpCZ8BTAJwEEaaBDATwApMBnWgLjCewsANGELUAtpz4NmLADwB5AEYArKgQB8ASjABvVGEOiJnMAF5jVSQDpylWmzFXzGvTSr5MNUvhqYqANwAvloBBkbunt6WkmFBQA). Your question quality would improve if you'd include a `flow.org/try` link demonstrating your issue

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried that link but error does not occur there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error says your annotation is missing. Add return type annotation to function

```
function add(x: number, y: number): number {
return x + y;
```

}

Comment: thanks for reply. It worked, error is not coming now. But how you got to know function return type annotation will fix error. From error 'Missing type annotation for `T`.' it does not indicate function return type annotation missing. From error I thought annotation missing in this line items = items.filter(item => {return true;});.

Comment: In case it helps someone, I was using filter to generate a variable, and got the same error. The type annotation had to go on the variable declaration like this: const filteredStrings: Array<string> = allStrings.filter((string) => string !== 'exclude'). I  agree this is one of Flow's most unhelpful messages.